# Where can I find the style xml resource that is referenced by style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, styles

I'm working through the book 'Android Programming' (2nd Edition) by the Big Nerd Ranch Guide. Page 152 contains the markup:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/crime_title_label"
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        />
```

Then page 154 states that "A style is an XML resource that contains attributes that describe how a widget should look and behave. For example, the following is a style resource that configures a widget with a larger-than-normal text size."

```
<style name="BigTextStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">3dp</item>
</style>
```

For the style that is referenced in `style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"`, how can I find its XML resource, which would be the equivalent of the BigTextStyle markup above?

Comment: You can try to create a Custom style for this in `res -> values -> styles.xml`

Comment: The style that the markup references is already in the program. I'm not asking how to create a custom style but how to find out what attributes this style defines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the refernces of the internal Android styles in the project:

```
External libraries -> Android API XX Platform -> res -> values -> themes{material/leanback/holo/device_defaults}.xml
```

Comment: Thanks. I know how to add an external library, but not how to follow the path you describe. How do I get to the first step 'External libraries'? Is it a menu item within Android Studio?

Comment: Press "Alt + 1" -> Project tab (not Android) -> External libraries (at the bottom).

Comment: Thanks. These resources define the themes i.e. for each theme, which styles it uses. What I am after is a definition of the style listSeparatorTextViewStyle, which would state what properties that style provides. Reference: "viewing the actual source code for these styles and themes will give you a better understanding of what style properties each one provides" from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles

Comment: Just go to the base parent: `..\sdk\platforms\android-23\data\res\values\styles.xml`. There is a base style `Widget.TextView.ListSeparator`. It's definition can also be found here [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml#508). If this comment does not suit you, then I don't understand what you would like to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. listSeparatorTextViewStyle isn't a style itself, but instead points to a style.